# what diffrence Int a => a -> String vs Int -> String

Tags: haskell

What is the difference between `Int a => a -> String` and `Int -> String`?

Success:

```
f1 :: Int -> String
```

Error:

```
f1 :: Int a => a -> String

f1 n = show n
```

Comment: What's the actual question here?  See [ask]

Comment: I guess you came from c/c++,  `Int a` doesn't mean `a` is an `Int`. Recommend reading [lyahfgg](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses)

Answer (score 3):

`Int` is a concrete type, so it cannot be used to create a constraint. Type classes (with kind `* -> Constraint`) like `Num` are used to create constraints.

Nor do you need to. The purpose of a constraint is to specify that a type variable like `a` must be a type that is an instance of a particular class. Something like `Int a` could only mean "a type `a` that is also type `Int`", and there is only one such type (surprise: `Int`) for which that is true, so you just write `Int -> String`.

A constraint like `Num a => a -> String` defines the type of a function that takes an argument of any type that implements `Num`, which could be `Int`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, or some other appropriate type.